# strcpy() is not working

Tags: c, string

I am trying to find hash of a number and copy to a string using strcpy(), but copy operation is not working properly.
Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

#define DIGEST_LENGTH 4
unsigned char *perform_hash(unsigned char *string){
        unsigned char *temp_hash = NULL;
        unsigned char digest[DIGEST_LENGTH], mdString[DIGEST_LENGTH*2+1];
        int i = 0;
        SHA_CTX ctx;
        SHA1_Init(&ctx);
        SHA1_Update(&ctx, string, strlen(string));
        SHA1_Final(digest, &ctx);

        for (i = 0; i < DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
                sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);
        printf("SHA1 digest{%s}: %s\n",string,mdString);
        temp_hash = mdString;
        printf("\nRET HASH:::%s",temp_hash);
        return temp_hash;
}

void main(){
        char *temp = NULL;
        unsigned char *hash_nonce = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)* 50);// FREEEEEE
        memset(hash_nonce, 0,50);
        temp = perform_hash("7c1824c5");
        strcpy(hash_nonce,temp);
        printf("\nHASH_NONCE:::%s\n",hash_nonce);
        temp = NULL;
}
```

Output:

> SHA1 digest{7c1824c5}: c79851b5
>
> RET HASH:::c79851b5
>
> HASH_NONCE::: �9�

Using strncpy() instead of strcpy()

> strncpy(hash_nonce,temp,strlen(temp));

Output :

> SHA1 digest{7c1824c5}: c79851b5
>
> RET HASH:::c79851b5
>
> HASH_NONCE:::

Comment: Which book are you reading? Because this is just one of many common errors which books tend to address early on... and I'd rather you didn't repeat frequently asked questions...

Comment: Besides your problem with returning invalid memory, you have another problem. `strncpy(hash_nonce,temp,strlen(temp));` This will not copy the terminating `\0` of your string because `strlen` is nearly always one byte too short.

Comment: also, be wary of passing your nonce to SHA as a string if you want to implement this algorithm in other languages as well.  The translation from char->byte is dependent on the character set.  Since your nonce appears to be hexadecimal, making the function take a byte-array and length would be more readily portable.

Answer (score 1):

`temp_hash = mdString;`

`mdString` is a local variable that is out of scope as soon as the function ends. And you are accessing it when it's life time is over invoking **undefined behavior**.(You are accessing it in `strcpy()` ) Get rid of this allocating dynamic memory.

```
char *mdString = malloc(DIGEST_LENGTH*2+1);
```

With proper checks after dynamic allocation and freeing it after working on it.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better: `unsigned char *perform_hash(unsigned char *string, unsigned char *result);`

Comment: @Yashas.: That's a different case. You are passing the array I guess (which decays into pointer)..and you store the hash in `result`. That works. Here I showed where the program behavior is out of hand for OP.

Comment: @coderredoc mdString is assigned to temp_hash inorder to avoid complie time warning                                                                                       
 "warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
          return mdString;"

Comment: @paru.: Yes, that's why there is the problem. You are accessing memory that you shouldn't. That's why compiler gives the warning also. Function returns local variables address whichs storage duration ends when the function call ends. And that's it. After that if you acess it, it's error.

Comment: Don't you think it'd make more sense to take storage from an argument than `malloc` here?

Comment: @Sebivor.:You meant that to pass the `result` var to the function -and we use it. Yes that's an way to go too. The hash logic can be separated from the all these. That would work too. Again these leaves the OP with some choice. Kind of like design issue.

Comment: Yes, and the C standard mostly chooses one choice over the other, which allows you, the user of the C standard, to choose whether you want to functions like `fscanf` and `sprintf` to operate upon memory with dynamic, automatic OR static storage duration at your discretion. Being given the choice constitutes additional functionality, as far as downstream programmers are concerned.

Comment: Imagine if you had to `free` every pointer you pass to `fscanf`, or every array which would be "produced" using `sprintf`... This would have horrific implications upon your CPU cache, right?

Comment: My bad. This is a point I should pose in the comments section for the question or as an edit request, but it does seem like the extra mile you could go through in the future, if you're keen on helping to set a good example.